# how to display json in blade laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have four tables. `inspections`, `requisitions`, `infractions` and `encouragements`.

Migration for inspections table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('inspections', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('requisition_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('encouragement_data')->nullable(true);
        $table->text('infraction_data')->nullable(true);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('requisition_id')->references('id')->on('requisitions')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

[image: inspections]

For example   {"1":"0"}

1 for id of infractions table and 0 for check or uncheck the checkbox I mentioned the example here: https://www.laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-store-all-checkboxes-in-laravel

Migration for requisitions table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('requisitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('school_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('inspector_user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('type');
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->boolean('approved');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('inspector_user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Migration for infractions table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('infractions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('score');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

[image: infractions]

Migration for encouragements table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('encouragements', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('unit_score');
        $table->integer('max_score');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

There are `encouragement_data` and `infraction_data` fields  in `inspections` table. And I create a form and store the infractions and encouragements form like JSON in site https://www.laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-store-all-checkboxes-in-laravel

Now I create  a new view. for display JSON title of `infractions` table. How should I do?

InspectionController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $inspections = Inspection::latest()->whereNotNull('infraction_data')->get();
    return view('Admin.list-violations-school.all', compact('inspections'));
}
```

inspections.blade.php

```
@foreach($inspections as $inspection)
    <?php $infraction_data = json_decode(json_encode($inspection->infraction_data),TRUE); ?>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $infraction_data["id"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $infraction_data["title"] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I get this error.

> Undefined index: id

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're `return view('Admin.list-violations-school.all', compact('inspections'));`, you're returning a view with access to a variable called $inspections. $inspections is now an array because `compact()` is a helper that converts an object into an array.

If in your page you do `dd($inspections)` (before the foreach for example), you'll be able to see the object you are working with in your view.

Also, you don't need to decode json because

1. you're not working with a json object but an array
2. If you ever want to work with a json object, you should json_decode first and not every iteration

.

```
@foreach($inspections as $inspection)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $inspection["infraction_data"]["id"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $inspection["infraction_data"]["title"] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get this error: `Trying to get property of non-object `

Comment: OK, I want to display id, title, How should I do?

Comment: Start off by editing your post with the content of $inspections by using dd($inspections) and remove the migrations. We just need to know the relationship your model has and what is the content of $inspections

Comment: How should I do?